# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'decouple' while creating a flask URL shortener app

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, python-decouple

I ran into this error while trying to initiate my database, even though I have python-decouple installed. I am new to programming so I will attach images of the error to see if anybody can figure out exactly what the problem is. [This is the config.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/du5SU.png)
[This is the **init**.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lf2Ml.png)
[This is the pip file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8k3g.png)

I had looked up the error and confirmed I was using the right Interpreter for my Environment. I also tried installing "decouple", but I still got the same error. I had to uninstall it and then re-install python-decouple but the error still persists.

[The pip list and pipenv run pip list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzLFQ.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please edit your question to include exactly what commands you ran to install python-decouple and your code.

Comment: Could you run `pipenv --venv` to check where is the location of virtual environment?

Comment: Please do not post images of your code (or links to images of your code). That makes it harder for us to work with your code, it makes your question less discoverable, and it makes the question much less useful to future readers if the links expire (and images render the question inaccessible to people using assistive devices such as screen readers). Put the code/configuration/etc in your question, as text, formatted as a code sample.

Comment: @Jasmijn I used `pipenv install python-decouple`

Comment: @Dauros /Users/dr_kay/.local/share/virtualenvs/Shorten-Z_ReIS7H This is the location after I ran the command you suggested. And it corresponds to the Interpreter I'm using.

Comment: @larsks I'm sorry about that. This is the first time I'm using Stack. I'll edit the question. I used pictures because I felt maybe someone will see something that I missed from the image.

Comment: Then prefix any `flask` command with `pipenv run`, so the correct venv is selected.

Comment: @Dauros that worked! Thanks a lot! Thanks to everybody who contributed.